# Does Sony NP-F type (generic) batteries have any over discharge protection circuitry inside?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, batteries

I use these Sony NP-F550 or NP-F570 Li-PO generic batteries (8.4V) for video light and for powering my DIY projects.

I've read you shouldn't discharge a 8.4V Li-ion (it's a double 3.7V cell inside the casing) below 6.0V.

I thought that these batteries had some sort of discharge limit circuitry inside. That they would "turn off" when below a certain voltage. But when using them in some Arduino projects, they do discharge until the Arduino turns off (below 5V), as there seems to be no protection at all.

Does anybody knows if it's normal for this kind of battery to discharge beyond the safe point? There's a PCB circuit inside, and I can't put it to charge in a regular Li-PO charger. It charges normally in a NP-F specific charger. Sometimes a battery can go down to 20% amount of charge (as the LCD in the charger shows).

Comment: Datasheet link in your question, please.

Comment: @Transistor Unfortunately all I can find is specs., like voltage, capacity and dimensions.  As it's a complete product (A battery) Sony, or any third party manufacturer, has not made available it's datasheet for download. I can open a damaged one and take pictures of the internal circuit PCB, if it helps

Comment: If you still have a damaged one, yes that would help @Rodrigo